# How to set the width of every umlusecase using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-uml

I am using [`TikZ-UML` awesome package](https://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/doc/tikzumlmanual.pdf) and I am having trouble with defining a global configuration of a UML diagram.

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\tikzumlset{fill usecase=white}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlsystem}[x=6] {Name}
        \umlusecase[width=2.5cm] {case 1}
        \umlusecase[x=5,width=2.5cm] {case 2}
        \umlusecase[x=5,y=-2,width=2.5cm] {case 3}
    \end{umlsystem}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: With width command]

I want to set `width=2.5cm` to **every** `umlusecase`. I tried with

```
\tikzumlset{fill usecase=white,every umlusecase/.style={width=2.5cm}}
```

(deleting all `width=2.5cm` in `umlusecase`'s) but it does not work:

[image: Without width]

Does anyone know how to generalize the property?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the code it is not intended to work. All settings are defined within `umlusecase`, so you had to patch the command.

Comment: @TeXnician thanks! So the only way is doing it manually?

Comment: At least that's the way the package is supposed to work. Maybe someone is able to provide a nice patch (my first attempt failed and I do not want to redefine the whole command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work. I used TeXnician's idea of patching the `\umlusecase` macro to remove the resetting of the `/usecase/style` style, and then use `usecase/style/.style={text width=2.5cm}` instead of your version to set the width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\xpatchcmd{\umlusecase}
  {style/.style={}}
  {}
  {}{}

\tikzumlset{
   fill usecase=white,
   usecase/style/.style={text width=2.5cm}
   }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlsystem}[x=6] {Name}
        \umlusecase {case 1}
        \umlusecase[x=5] {case 2}
        \umlusecase[x=5,y=-2] {case 3}
    \end{umlsystem}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```